# Why I keep having this THEOS error?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos

```
      opt/theos is not writable. Please run `/opt/theos/bin/bootstrap.sh                         
      substrate` manually, with privileges.
      make: *** [before-all] Error 1
```

I'm trying the `make` method of THEOS but it keeps poping this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **sudo make** (then enter your password).